# Object.assign() clone still linked

Tags: javascript

Why does the code below create and infinitely deep object? I'm assuming its something with `const` and scope. How can I prevent this?

```js
const DEFAULT_PROP = {children: []}
class Class {
  constructor(prop = {}) {
    assignProperties(this, prop, DEFAULT_PROP);
  }
}

//Loops props in the default and if they are given use them, if not use fallback
function assignProperties(element, given, defaults) {
    for (let property in defaults) {
        if (property in given) {
            element[property] = given[property];
        } else {
            element[property] = defaults[property];
        }
    }
}

var parent = new Class();

parent.children.push(new Class());

console.log(parent);
```

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061708/javascript-object-assignment-infinite-recursion) and it seems that when I change `Class.children` I'm actually change the `DEFAULT_PROP.children` too so that I'm just referencing itself. How can I avoid this?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133582/assign-value-not-reference-in-javascript) I should be using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a unlinked clone to then copy from, but my implementation did not work. (See below)

```js
const DEFAULT_PROP = {children: []}
class Class {
  constructor(prop = {}) {
    assignProperties(this, prop, DEFAULT_PROP);
  }
}

//Loops props in the default and if they are given use them, if not use fallback
function assignProperties(element, given, defaults) {
    let defaultsClone = Object.assign({}, defaults);

    for (let property in defaultsClone) {
        if (property in given) {
            element[property] = given[property];
        } else {
            element[property] = defaultsClone[property];
        }
    }
}

var parent = new Class();

parent.children.push(new Class());

console.log(parent);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What you're doing in your code is a shallow copy. `children` still is connected to `DEFAULT_PROPS` attribute. You need to do a deep copy. See this question; a comment under the first answer mentions this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: So its sounds like I'm supposed to use `eval()`, but what I have complex data?